# what is the difference between query() and rawQuery() in sqlite and which one is more efficient and goog

Tags: android, sqlite

I am learning to implement databases in android , i came across this query() and rawQuery() , i want to know the difference between them and which one is efficient in android

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From API Doc:

```
public void execSQL (String sql)
```

Execute a single SQL statement that is NOT a SELECT or any other SQL statement that returns data.

```
public Cursor rawQuery (String sql, String[] selectionArgs)
```

Runs the provided SQL and returns a Cursor over the result set.

If you want to e.g. `CREATE TABLE` that does not return values you can use `execSQL()`, if you want a `Cursor` as result use `rawQuery()` (=`SELECT` statements).

Looking at SQLiteDatabase.java in the android source shows that the query(..) ends up calling the QueryBuilder to build the query as a single string and then it essentially calls rawQuery(). They should be roughly equivalent, assuming that you also did the same work to build your own statement.

Comment: thank you very much , that is the kind of explanation i am waiting for.